# $A\subseteq \{1,2,3, \ldots 2000\}, $ and for any $a,b\in A,\; |a-b|$ is not equal to 4 or 7,

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$A\subseteq \{1,2,3,\ldots2000\}$, and for any $a,b\in A,$ $|a-b|$ is not equal to 4 or 7. Then, at most, how many element does $A$ contain?

For general condition,$|a-b|$ is not equal to $i$ or $j, (i,j \in A)$, how to solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $182\times 5=910$. An optimal solution is
$\lbrace x\in[1,2000] | x\equiv 1,3,4,6 \ \text{ or } 9 \ \textsf{mod} \ 11\rbrace$.
(with a little more work, one can show that there are exactly 
$183$ optimal solutions and describe them).

Call a set $A$ of integers distinguished $|a-b|$ is not equal to
$4$ or $7$ for any $a,b\in A$.

**Lemma 1.** If $A \subseteq [1,10]$ is distinguished, then
$A$ contains at most five elements.

**Proof of lemma 1.** Each of the sets $\lbrace 1,5\rbrace$,
$\lbrace 2,9\rbrace$, $\lbrace 3,7\rbrace$, $\lbrace 4,8\rbrace$,
$\lbrace 6,10\rbrace$ has at most one element in common with $A$.

**Lemma 2** If $A\subseteq [1,11]$ is distinguished, then
$A$ contains at most five elements.

**Proof of lemma 2.** By lemma 1, we may assume $11\in A$ (and hence
$4\not\in A,7\not\in A$). Using the symmetry $x\mapsto 12-x$, we may
also assume $1\in A$ (and hence $5\not\in A,8\not\in A$). If $6\in A$, 
then $A$ does not contain $2$ or $10$, so $A\subseteq \lbrace 1,3,6,9,11 \rbrace$
and we are done. We may therefore assume that $6\not\in A$. Then
$A$ can be written $A=\lbrace 1,11 \rbrace\cup B$, where $B$ is a subset
of $\lbrace 2,3,9,10 \rbrace$ has at most one element in common with each
of $\lbrace 2,9\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 3,10\rbrace$. This concludes the proof.

**Lemma 3** If $A\subseteq [1,2000]$ is distinguished, then
$A$ contains at most 910 elements.

**Proof of lemma 3.** Apply lemma 2 on the nine-element set $A\cap [1,9]$, 
and on each of the $181$ eleven-element sets $A\cap [11k-1,11k+9]$.

Answer (score 2):

Write out the numbers $\bmod 4$ in distinct lists:

$1,5,9,13,\dots 1997$

$2,6,10,14,\dots 1998$

$3,7,11,15 \dots 1999$

$4,8,12,16\dots 2000$

Transform it into a graph that looks as follows but with $500$ columns, we want a maximum independent set of the graph:

[image]

Comment: And so? What is the maximum size of an independent set in such a graph? How many vertices can we choose among $28$ consecutive vertices?

Comment: For istance, by selecting $\{1,2,3,4,12,13,14,15,23,24,25,26,\ldots,1992,1993,1994,1995\}$ we have an independent set of size $728$ (density $\approx\frac{4}{11}$). Can we do better?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  In fact ,using computer, I find an independent set of size 909.

Comment: @ModdedBear Good idea, but the transformation is seemly useless.Because if contain 1,2,3,4, the size of the independent set is 728.But I find a independent set of size 909.

Comment: @lanse2pty: Could you write enough of that set that we might see a pattern?